# I love someone and he died(make dua for him;_;)...i want to be with him in aakhirat I want to stay Unmarried is it ok according to islam?

Tags: nikah, dua, jannah, love

I don't want to get married... I want to be with him please remember him in your duas

Answer (score 0):

Asalam Alaykum Sister Syeda,

I am very sorry for your loss.

Allah knows best of your sadness,
and what you want,

and in Jannah we will be in whatever place that is the happiest for us in our wishes and such,

and all of our sadness will be gone forever.

But Sister Syeda
Prophet Muhammad Peace be upon him, said.

"Marriage is a part of my Sunnah,
and my tradition,
so, whoever abandons marriage is not from my followers, or my believers."

This is what he said.

those who abandon marriage will be amongst the losers in the Akhirah

I understand that you love your husband and I pray for your happiness Sister Syeda,

but your love for your husband should not allow you to go against Allah,
to go against Islam, or the Holy Prophet (PBUH).

You should pray for Allah to help you with your sadness and grieving,

but you should also pray to Allah to help you find another husband that will be the best for you,

the best for your life,
and for your Iman.

I know this test is hard,

but following Islam
in the right way is always the answer.

As long as you are a good Muslim,

and a good wife to your next husband,

Insha'Allah you will see the blessing of your next marriage in this life or in the next.

Allah knows what is best for us,

and we should trust Allah in his plan even if right now you don't feel happy about things.

Our decisions should be to Follow Islam and the Holy Prophets Sunnah (PBUH).

I understand you love your husband and I'm sorry for your loss Sister,

but abandoning marriage is haram, and this can definitely lead you down a path that is wrong,

and that can completely destroy your Faith,
and You won't realize this destruction has happened.
until it is too late.

Allah will never place a test on you Sister Syeda that is too much for you to bear,
even though it might feel like it.

Allah's plan is the best always,
and Allah knows of your suffering and your sadness,

but Part of Allah's test on you Syeda in this,
is to test if you love your husband more,
or do you love Allah and the Holy Prophet (PBUH) more?

Insha'Allah if you follow the right way you will see the benefit in the end.
and you will know that Allah's plan for you is the best.

My prayers go out to you sister Syeda,

and I hope you realize what I'm telling you is the right answer,

and I hope you don't forget to follow it, for your Iman's sake.

Asalam Alaykum sister Syeda,

May Allah's Blessings be upon you.